# Relationship between the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, Brouwer's fixed point theorem (for the ball) and Tucker's lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Which of these - the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, the Brouwer's fixed point theorem (for the ball) and Tucker's lemma implies which? I'm a little confused with this. I suspect they may be equivalent. If that is indeed so, can someone please provide a proof (or a link to a proof) of the equivalence of the three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tucker's lemma and the Borsuk-Ulam theorem can be proved almost along the same lines (triangulations + Sperner's lemma or Ki Fan's lemma) and they are essentially equivalent. Brouwer's theorem is a consequence: however, Brouwer's theorem does not imply Borsuk-Ulam (at least, as far as I know). Have a look at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323057/is-there-a-simple-proof-of-borsuk-ulam-given-brouwer), too.

Comment: You're correct. It's Tucker=Borsuk>Brouwer. Thanks.